# Unable to join DBA Stack Exchange using Facebook?

Tags: support

I have been able to join here with the same process, and I am a member at penty of other Stack Exchange sites, but I cannot join [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) (or its Meta) using the steps below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Guys, if the error message literally says *it's not you, it's us*, can we refrain from downvoting a legitimate request for support? I don't know what's going on, but OP isn't acting confrontational or entitled, so unless you know, concretely, what the problem is (in which case *you should answer*), let's default to mutual respect.

Comment: thanks bro, i couldnt think of anywhere else to post

Comment: Well, technically, you should ask on [meta.dba.se], but if you're prevented from making an account there, you're 100% right that MSE is the place to ask.

Comment: Thats correct, i tried there too first, but same problem.

Comment: Related (and recent): *[Joing the Quant Stack Exchange gives an error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277117/273503)* and *[Can't join a community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277116/300411)*.

Comment: This is fixed now, though you may need to update your display name yourself.