# Can't join a community

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, user-accounts

I look for similar questions to this one but my problem is different. I want to join this community:

[image]

so I click in

[image]

but I got this error:

[image]

but then, I found that the community is already in list of communities:

[image]

However, if I click on the community, I'm an anonymous member

[image]

and even I have the option to join again

[image]

but if I click on it, the problem starts again :( what can I do?

Comment: Related (and recent): *[Joing the Quant Stack Exchange gives an error](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277117/273503)* and *[Unable to join DBA Stack Exchange using Facebook?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277088/273503)*.

Comment: The same happened to me when trying to sign up on Stack Overflow. At the very moment there seems some issue with sign up and log in (I also experience spurious errors when trying to log in, but it eventually works).  SE staff is aware of the general  problem.

Comment: Is there any way to "un-join" a community?

Comment: If you did essentially nothing so far you can delete your account directly (there is a button on the userpage), if not you need to contact SE about it. See  http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account for details. But for the former you need to access the account.

Comment: I uploaded all the screenshots now that I got the privileges to do it :) regarding to deleting my account, well, I wouldn't, because it may happen again and again, specially if there are more users with the same problem

Comment: The username in "your" (given you appear unable to access it) freelancing account is quite odd... The fact that it's a guid, or appears to be, may give the team some clue as to what may be going on.... (Or it may just be a strange side effect of the issue.)

Comment: After a log out and a log in on other sites, I was now able to access my oddly created SO account, that was not synced properly. I then deleted it, and created a new one. And it worked.

Comment: Uhm, it is a technological problem. The social obstacle can be higher. :-)

Answer (score 5):

This was fixed last week by [Geoff Dalgas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas) - a backfill was ran (but the user name on the joined community still need to be edited directly is some cases).

Comment: But what was the problem? Any juicy details? :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - not entirely sure. Account syncing wasn't run when joining a new community, if I got it right. There was a job that fixed those that ran nightly, but refactoring happened.

Answer (score 0):

I found something interesting: apparently, Freelancer is a "beta" community, which it may mean that it's still in development.  But now if you click on the corner, Stackexchange button:

[image]

you have the possibility of editing your communities.

There is still something "**weird**": when I check my user in the Freelancer community, I still see that long name, but then, I have created [the question I wanted to ask](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/online-magazine-blog-in-wordpress-seo-question) and my user-name appears correctly there.

Thanks everyone for the ideas that led me to this solution!

Comment: @404 the fact is that now I can post in that community with my username and before I couldn't. The only change I did was that one. Unless you tell me you are one of the website developers and that's not the way it is...

Comment: even my profile has been updated there and the weird username has been replaced with my username! :D