# Joing the Quant Stack Exchange gives an error

Tags: bug, status-completed

I am trying to join the Quant Stack Exchange: https://quant.stackexchange.com/

When I try to join it gives me an error "Oops" something went wrong. There are no further details, and it has been like for many attempts and in different browsers.

I have joined other Stack Exchanges with no problem. Also, I am attempting to join through a Facebook profile, which is how I have joined the other sites.

Comment: Related? [Can't join a community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277116/300411)

Comment: Yea, that looks related, but there is no answer to that question as well. I assumed maybe the site was down temporarily, but it seems I am still unable to join Quant. The Quant site is in Beta if it makes any difference.

Comment: And again last night; for the DBA community: *[Unable to join DBA Stack Exchange using Facebook?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277088/273503)*.